The issue of public/private signals when generating zero-knowledge proofs with Circom
Circom is a circuit language capable of generating zero-knowledge proofs, which involves some input signals and output signals. I have a question: if all the input and output signals during the generation of the zero-knowledge proof are public, meaning that there are no private inputs at all when generating the proof, is the zero-knowledge proof still considered valid? In other words, does the zero-knowledge proof protocol allow for the absence of private inputs?
I tried compiling and generating a zero-knowledge proof with all input and output signals being public, and it worked fine. However, does this really make sense?

This may fit better on [security.se] unless it involves code. Check the [tour] and [ask].
